# Python cancel while loop via new window button

Tags: python

So here´s the deal. I have a button. That button triggers a while loop and opens a new window with a "cancel" button. Through that cancel-button I want to terminate the while loop.

NEW APPROACH:

```
def process():
    parent,child = Pipe()
    p = process(target=new_window(),args=(child))
    p.start()
    parent.send("True")
    while true:
        if child.recv()!="False":
            do something
        else:
            p.join()


def new_window(p):
    id = "cancel"
    window = Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry("240x160")

    state = p.recv()

    def closewindow():
        global state
        state = "False"
        p.send(state)
        window.destroy()

    label = Label(window, text="Überwache...").place(x=90,y=60)
    buttonc = Button(window,text="Abbrechen!",fg="black",command=closewindow).place(relx=0.35, rely=0.5)
```

The idea is that the parent (def process) executes the while loop as long as it doesn´t get a "False" from the child process (new_window).
Do you see any errors? Can´t test it right now, since the code replacing my placeholder "do something" is another difficult task...

OLD POST:

state variable

```
state = bool(True)
```

button that triggers loop and new window

```
button3 = Button(containerd,text="Starte Überwachung",fg="black",height=10,width=16,command=sound)
```

function new window

```
def new_window():

    id = "cancel"
    window = Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry("240x160")
    def closewindow():
        global state
        state = bool(False)
        window.destroy()

    label = Label(window, text="Überwache...").place(x=90,y=60)
    buttonc = Button(window,text="Abbrechen!",fg="black",command=closewindow).place(relx=0.35, rely=0.5)
```

function while loop

```
def sound():
    global inp
    global state

    new_window()
    while state:
        l,data = inp.read()
        if l > 60:
            subprocess.call(['/home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/cycle.sh'],shell=True)
        else:
            continue
```

The problem is the new window never opens. The while loop keeps the button / programm "occupied". Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I dont see anywhere what UI toolkit do you use. Anyway, using global variables is not a good idea. I'd recommend you to use `multiprocessing` -  start the another process via `multiprocessing.Process`, and share the state by `multiprocessing.Pipe`

Comment: Hey. What do you mean by UI Toolkit? Maybe it helps if I tell you that it´s written in pycharm on windows and executed on my Raspberry Pi 2 Jessie. So instead of `while state:` I use this `multiprocess`?